# How do I see the guid while debugging VB code in VS2008?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

On my last machine I had created a way to see a GUID variable while debugging by hovering over it.  I don't remember what it was (a visualizer?).

I have a new 64 bit machine with vs2008 - is there anyway to mouseover a guid value and have it appear?  What makes guid's so special that their value doesn't show like most variables?

Comment: Which guid are you talking about?

Comment: are you talking about a variable of type GUID that you declared?

Comment: yes - variable of type GUID that I declared (in Visual Basic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a blog article on how to do this awhile back.  It doesn't require a visualizer and the results will just show up automatically.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2007/09/28/customizing-displays-in-the-debugger-for-system-types.aspx

Also, this is fixed in VS2010 such that the GUID will always display inline by default.  No extra steps necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this visualizer:

http://devmatter.blogspot.com/2006/04/guid-debugger-visualizer-for-visual.html

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it works in Visual Studio 2008.

EDIT:  Here is the posting from the developers site:  http://www.codechimp.org/Blog/post/New-Download-GUID-Visualizer-for-Visual-Studio-2005.aspx   Doesn't look like he has worked on it since then.

Comment: thanks - this is certainly close.  

I also see that this was requested for VS2005 in MS Connect:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=89801&wa=wsignin1.0 - I am not this works in 2008 64 bit - so still hoping others will have some ideas